# What is the best way to execute the same php script on different server?

Tags: php, security

I have a script called MY_SCRIPT which I need to upload on different server (A, B and C) for performance issue. This script is the same for all servers.

What is the best way to do that to have the less maintenance about it ?

I was thinking about that :

```
<?php
eval(file_get_contents("http://user:passwd@www.mysecurewebsite.com/myscript.txt"));
?>
```

What do you think about this ?

Comment: i can't see anything but performance *loss*, security hole and unnecessary complexity in this approach... But if you really want to... use `include(<url_of_the_remote_script>);`; you need to enable the [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) configuration option to do this.

Comment: Implement uploading the file to each server as part of your release cycle. Creating connections to remote systems and loading files from them will create performance issues rather than solve them as there is a much larger overhead on every single request than there is to load a local file.

Comment: Epic. Second epic question today. Cool Tuesday I'd say. Also please use the search, this *has* been asked before (so don't feel to ashamed). (what you do is called remote execution and remote code injection and you normally want to prevent that at all cost. take care.)

Comment: Push changes to different remotes, then run a post-commit hook just in case. `eval(file_get_contents())` just makes my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a deployment tool to deploy this file automatically to several servers. Something like [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com), [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com), [Chef](http://opscode.com), [Capistrano](http://capify.org) or the like.